# Modern Desktop Environment for RHEL 6

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, rhel-6, desktop-environments

I'm currently forced to work with a machine running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6. Since I'm usually working with the latest Ubuntu version and a corresponding modern desktop environment, I was quite disappointed that RHEL 6 by default only supports gnome and KDE versions from 2009. Working in any of them is just painful and feels like a time travel to the last century.

I'm not allowed to upgrade to RHEL 7 or install a different OS, but I have sudo privileges.

Is there a way how I could get any modern desktop environment up and running without an OS upgrade? I don't even care which one, I'd just like to have a version that's not 6 years old...

Comment: Maybe tapping into EPEL and other repos might give you the ability to upgrade the Gnome desktop without rebasing the system. Might I ask why you are not allowed to install another OS, does your company not care about productivity?

Comment: It's due to internally used, highly customized tools (for building etc.) that are integrated into their custom RHEL software repos. Setting this up on another system would allegedly be rather painful...